# Using UIMenuController in iOS 14 for UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios14, uimenucontroller

There are some tutorials about how to use `UIMenuController` inside `UICollectionView` but in iOS 14 it is semideprecated:

```
// These methods provide support for copy/paste actions on cells.
// All three should be implemented if any are.
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("collectionView:contextMenuConfigurationForItemAtIndexPath:", ios(6.0, 13.0));
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(nullable id)sender API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("collectionView:contextMenuConfigurationForItemAtIndexPath:", ios(6.0, 13.0));
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(nullable id)sender API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("collectionView:contextMenuConfigurationForItemAtIndexPath:", ios(6.0, 13.0));
```

In the same time `UIMenuController` still exists in iOS 14. How to use it for cells now?

Answer (score 0):

The UICollectionViewDelegate will not trigger those method you post after iOS 14. But we still can get FirstResponder which UIMenuController need from UIView. Hits. UICollectionView still is UIView

Full Code:

```swift
protocol Menuable {
    func menuAction(_ sender: Any?)
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell, Menuable {
...
    func menuAction(_ sender: Any?){...}
...
}

class MenuableCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    func setupLongpress() {
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPressGesture(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    func setupMenu() {
        let menuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "action", action: #selector(menuAction(_:)))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [menuItem]
        UIMenuController.shared.update()
    } 
    
    @objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.location(in: self)
        if sender.state == .began {
            guard let indexPath = indexPathForItem(at: point) else {
                return
            }
            
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            becomeFirstResponder()
            
            let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            
            let x: CGFloat = cell?.frame.midX ?? point.x
            let y: CGFloat = 10
            
            let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 10, height: 10)
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                UIMenuController.shared.showMenu(from: self, rect: rect)
            } else {
                UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(rect, in: self)
                UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc func menuAction(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard let indexPath = selectedIndexPath else {
            return
        }
        let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Menuable
        cell?.menuAction(sender)
    }
    
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(menuAction(_:)) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

// you should call setupLongpress() and setupMenu() after collection view init.
```

Comment: Do you have a source for the "will not trigger after iOS 14" part?